# How to see if something( a variable ) is set?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
for msg in mbox:
        try:
            pprint.pprint(msg._headers, stream = f)
            tempdate = parser.parse(msg['Date'])
            newdate = str(tempdate)[:19]
            ip = msg['x-originating-ip']
            iplookup = (ip.strip("[]"))
            url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/{}'.format(iplookup)
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
            result = json.loads(response.decode('utf8'))
            f.write ('Country = ' + (result['country_name']) + '\n')
            f.write ('Region = ' + (result['region_name']) + '\n')
            f.write ('City = ' + (result['city']) + '\n')
```

However, not all emails have originiting IP. how can i check to see if the x orginiting ip is set? Something like an IF staement

```
       ip = msg['x-originating-ip']

       if (isset(ip):
           iplookup = (ip.strip("[]"))
            url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/{}'.format(iplookup)
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
            result = json.loads(response.decode('utf8'))
            f.write ('Country = ' + (result['country_name']) + '\n')
            f.write ('Region = ' + (result['region_name']) + '\n')
            f.write ('City = ' + (result['city']) + '\n')
        else:
             continue
```

Thats an example i thought of, but the isset function is from php, not python? Any ideas?

Comment: set means, it has non zero value or its `None` ?

Comment: None. Nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if 'x-originating-ip' in msg:
    ...
```

It uses the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). It only checks if the key is set, not what the value is - so it can still be `None` or `False` or an empty string or list or something. You can also use `'foo' not in x` instead of `not 'foo' in x`.

If you want to check that it's not `None` at the same time, for example, use [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead:

```
if msg.get('x-originating-ip') is not None:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check value of `x-originating-ip` is set or not using get.

```
ip = msg.get('x-originating-ip')
if ip: 
    ...
    ....
```